# Build a Lab color model in opencv

Tags: opencv, image-processing, color-space, lab-color-space

I need to create a color model based on the "a" and "b" channels of the Lab color space. I have successfully separated the three channels "L", "a" and "b" and I used this code to compute the mean and standard deviation for "a" and "b":

```
Scalar aMeanDev;
Scalar aStdDev;
meanStdDev(A, aMeanDev, aStdDev);
uchar aMean = aMeanDev.val[0];
uchar aStd = aStdDev.val[0];

Scalar bMeanDev;
Scalar bStdDev;
meanStdDev(B, bMeanDev, bStdDev);
uchar bMean = bMeanDev.val[0];
uchar bStd = bStdDev.val[0];
```

I really have no idea how to continue. The final output of this project would be to use the resulted color model for image segmentation.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please elaborate. I figured out what you have done. But what you want is so vague. Building a color model of your asking revolves around this function : `cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2LAB)`, what more do you want?

Comment: Basically I have to implement image segmentation functionality, working with Lab color model. My teacher said that I have to split the image by channels (did that) and compute the mean and standar deviations for each channel (also did that). But I don't know hot to continue..

Comment: I get it. Now you must segment the image based on the pixels. If the value of pixel is equal to or greater than [mean + 'x' deviations] then segment them. All other pixel values are not segmented and vice-versa. You teacher is right. Your teacher wanted you to proceed from here that's all. :)